# How to get the linestring of a way in postgis with pg_snapshot schema

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have loaded some data from openstreetmap using osmosis and its pg_snapshot schema. This results in a table `ways`which contains a list of `nodes`referenced by their ids:

```
select w.nodes from ways as w where w.tags->'railway'='rail' limit 1;
         nodes
-----------------------
{358482292,358482290}
```

and in a separate table you have a geometry column for each node:

```
select st_astext(nodes.geom) from nodes where id = 358482292;
     st_astext
-----------------------------
POINT(6.1253475 45.9259597)
```

My question what query could give me a `LINESTRING` for each way created from the node list?

Answer (score 3):

When creating the database you want to apply the `osmosis/script/pgsnapshot_schema_0.6_linestring.sql` script **before** importing. This will cause osmosis to generate the linestrings. If you didn't do this before importing, it's possible to add a linestring column and use the SQL in the bulk load script to populate it, but this is very slow when operating on a full planet.

Answer (score 2):

while creating the schema, one should execute:

```
osmosis/script/pgsnapshot_schema_0.6_linestring.sql
```

to have a linestring for each way